# mySQL/PHP: SQL Statement, query and result assignment in ONE line?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to re-write the code below, maybe even with an `if (result > 0)` statement, in just one line (or simply shorter)?

```
// a simple query that ALWAYS gets ONE table row as result
$query  = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE this = that;");
$result = $query->fetch_object();
$id     = $result->id;
```

I've seen awesome, extremely reduced constructs like Ternary Operators ([here](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) and [here](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-shorthand-if-else-examples) - btw see the comments for even more reduced lines) putting 4-5 lines in one, so maybe there's something for single result SQL queries like the above.

Comment: Could just extend the DB library to do a `fetchOne()` type call. You'd still want proper error handling in there, as queries can, do, and WILL fail.

Comment: Always opt for clarity over terseness

Comment: @blockhead Can you please rewrite your comment ? It's not understandable for non-native english speakers. Merci !

Comment: @Panique blockhead simply stated that it is better to have clear code (easier to read and maintain) than to have unnecessary ternary operators that make the code harder to read just for the sake of saving a few characters.

Comment: My French is probably as bad (or worse!) than your english...but let's try: Toujours choisir pour plus de clarté au lieu de concision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could shorten

```
$query  = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE this = that;");
$result = $query->fetch_object();
$id     = $result->id;
```

to

```
$id = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE this = that")->fetch_object()->id;
```

but this, and the original code will emit errors, if any of the functions returns an unexpected response. Better to write:

```
$query  = $this->db->query("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE this = that");
if (!$query) {
     error_log('query() failed');
     return false;
}
$result = $query->fetch_object();
if (!$result) {
     error_log('fetch_object() failed');
     return false;
}
$id     = $result->id;
```